# Android Proteção Engenharia Reversa Cliente-Servidor

Tags: android, cliente-servidor, engenharia-reversa

Vejo que é muito comum aplicações `Android` (jogos por exemplo) serem modificadas através de `engenharia reversa`.

Mesmo usando `obfuscação` e outras técnicas anti engenharia reversa, é difícil manter uma aplicação Android completamente livre bisbilhoteiros, cheaters, etc.

Diante deste cenário, venho questionar qual a melhor maneira de manter íntegros a comunicação cliente-servidor, já que garantir a integridade da aplicação é uma tarefa difícil.

- Como garantir que os dados que chegam no servidor vêm realmente de uma aplicação íntegra (não modificada através de `engenharia reversa`)?

Comment: Esse tipo de garantia simplesmente não é possível. Você pode dificultar ao máximo atrás de várias técnicas, mas nenhuma vai efetivamente **garantir** a integridade ou identidade da sua aplicação.

Comment: @Androiderson disse tudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `Protocol Buffers`, do próprio Google.

`Protocol Buffers` é neutro a qualquer linguagem, plataforma, e tem uma maneira muito boa de serialização dos objetos. São flexíveis, eficientes e tem um mecanismo automatizado para serializar dados.

Além de ser mais eficiente que XML ou Json, caso seja interceptado, não é legível para humanos. Sua estrutura não permite fácil compreensão caso não tenha os arquivos chamados "contratos".

Você pode ter melhores referencias e como funciona e como implementar diretamente da [documentação oficial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview).

**Links úteis:**

-Github: https://github.com/google/protobuf

-5 Reasons to Use Protocol Buffers: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2014/06/05/choose-protocol-buffers/